# How to remove html audio element border?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to style html audio element. I managed to change the color but I cannot get rid of  from the tiny small border around? Anyone with ideas how to remove it?
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a code block.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to style audio tag, each browser implements this in there own way.. you can hide it and problematically link to each function button like: play, pause etc.. to your custom buttons, or you can use existing libraries that deal with this, like jPlayer > jplayer.org or many other libraries

Answer (score 1):

There is no consistent way for every browser to style HTML5  players with CSS.
and most browser don't support that
better solution is to turn off the controls , make your own player with HTML and CSS ,
then manage the functionality using JS .

Of course - you don't need to re-Invent the wheel , there is a lot of ready solution out there that might help you .